# form_builder drop down options codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to know why selected is not in options, but only in select tag
Here is my code:

```
$this->CI
     ->form_builder
     ->setField(
         'campus',
         'Campus', 
         'required', 
         array(
             'type'     => 'select'
             'options'  => $dropDownOptions,
             'selected' => $selected_campus,
             'value'    => $this->CI
                                ->EventModel
                                ->strCampus, 
         )
     )
```

Result will be:

```
  <select value="JKL" selected="selected" name="campus" id="campus" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" >
      <option value="ABC" >ABC</option>
      <option value="DEF" >DEF</option>
      <option value="GHI" >GHI</option>
      <option value="JKL" >JKL</option>
      <option value="MNO" >MNO</option>
      <option value="PQR" >PQR</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: what do you mean? clarify.

Comment: selected is in <Select ...> which should not happen. It should be in <option value="JFK" selected="selected">JFL</option>

Comment: is `form_builder` a standard Codeigniter library? I think you mean **Form Helper** . What documentations are you following?